# Installing Oracle 32 or 64 bit on a Windows Server 2019 to Import data into SQL server and use with Power BI

Tags: oracle, ssis, oracle-12c, powerbi, ssms

I am an Oracle noob and really struggling with this concept of 32 and 64 bit business with Oracle.

All I really want to do, is import data on a daily basis from an Oracle 12c DW into a local 2019 SQL Server and then connect Power BI on top of it.

The reason being that we are looking to move out of Oracle and into SQL Server and I need to PoC.

So far I have looked high and low and can't seem to figure out WHAT to INSTALL to access WHAT in oracle.

All I really need, if I have understood correctly is to install a Oracle CLIENT to be able to then use SSIS to build my ETL routines. BUT when I install 32bit client, it says need 64 bit client and when I install 64bit client it says it wants an ODAC. I have installed that too and still no success.

I am also struggling to understand what folder level goes into the PATH in the system environment variables.
It is so complicated in comparison to SQL Server, so I could really use your help in the following questions.

1. Given that SSMS is 32bit - Can I just install 32bit oracle client and ODAC - if so, which software do I download from Oracle and install - Can't tell the diff between xcopy and other versions (and can you tell me how to update the path)
2. Do I need to install x64 bit at all, given that I am on a 64bit workstation? If so, again, which software do I download.

My end goal is to be able to:

- Connect to ORACLE using SQL SERVER SSIS and import data on a daily basis via ETL routines
- as a temporary back up also connect to ORACLE using Power BI.

Comment: If your operating system is 64-bit then you must install the 64-bit Oracle client. Try the instant client for simplicity: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

Comment: @pmdba, that's wrong. It depends on your client whether you have to install 32-bit or 64-bit version. Of course, a 32-bit OS works only with 32-bit client but on 64-bit OS you can install either version (or even both)

Comment: When your SSMS is 32bit then you have to install the 32-bit Oracle Client. Looks like you messed up some installations, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit. So basically I need to install 32bit Client and ODAC?

Also what about path setting, do I need to explicitey create a new entry by calling it ORACLE_PATH?

Comment: The installer should set the PATH